# $\mathrm{R}^n$ for non-integer values of $n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

If I have a set of all possible $x$ for $x \in \mathrm{R}^n$ for non-natural number $n$, what meaning would this have and how would it be used?

For instance, if I had $\mathrm{R}^{2.5}$, would this be a set of something between 2-coordinates and 3-coordinates? Would it be only positive? Etc.

Thanks! I apologize in advance if this does not make sense.

Comment: There is a post somewhere on this site (or on MO) showing that this cannot be made sense of topologically

Comment: I got some hits for ["fractional cartesian product"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fractional+cartesian+product%22) that might be relevant.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ (with $n$ being a positive integer) is just shorthand for the Cartesian product $\underbrace{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\cdots\times \Bbb R}_{n\textrm{ times}}$. I don't think there's a standard definition for the notation when $n$ is not a positive integer.